# WebDriverException Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally

Tags: python, list, visual-studio-code, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools

I want to run multiple Chrome profiles, but only one profile should be able to open the link `facebook.com`, while the rest of the links should not be accessible

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import threading

def open_new_chrome(name_profile):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data")
    options.add_argument(r'--profile-directory='+ name_profile)
    service  = Service(executable_path="C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/python/chromedriver.exe")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service,options=options)
    try:
        # ...
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
        # ...
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error occurred:", e)
   
name_profile = [
    "Profile 55",
    "Profile 56",
    "Profile 74",
    "Profile 1"
]    
    
threads = [] 

for i in range(len(name_profile)):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=open_new_chrome, args=(name_profile[i],))
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()
    time.sleep(5)
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

```
Exception has occurred: WebDriverException
Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x006FA813+48355]
    (No symbol) [0x0068C4B1]
    (No symbol) [0x00595358]
    (No symbol) [0x005B3621]
    (No symbol) [0x005B0579]
    (No symbol) [0x005E0C55]
    (No symbol) [0x005E093C]
    (No symbol) [0x005DA536]
    (No symbol) [0x005B82DC]
    (No symbol) [0x005B93DD]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0095AABD+2539405]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0099A78F+2800735]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0099456C+2775612]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x007851E0+616112]
    (No symbol) [0x00695F8C]
    (No symbol) [0x00692328]
    (No symbol) [0x0069240B]
    (No symbol) [0x00684FF7]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x77246359+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x776A7B74+228]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x776A7B44+180]
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\python\code .py", line 14, in open_new_chrome
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service,options=options)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x006FA813+48355]
    (No symbol) [0x0068C4B1]
    (No symbol) [0x00595358]
    (No symbol) [0x005B3621]
    (No symbol) [0x005B0579]
    (No symbol) [0x005E0C55]
    (No symbol) [0x005E093C]
    (No symbol) [0x005DA536]
    (No symbol) [0x005B82DC]
    (No symbol) [0x005B93DD]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0095AABD+2539405]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0099A78F+2800735]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0099456C+2775612]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x007851E0+616112]
    (No symbol) [0x00695F8C]
    (No symbol) [0x00692328]
    (No symbol) [0x0069240B]
    (No symbol) [0x00684FF7]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x77246359+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x776A7B74+228]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x776A7B44+180]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.